# Meteor - Passing data between helpers, events and templates

Tags: javascript, templates, events, meteor, helper

I'm not sure how to approach my issue. Whether I should set my variables in my event to my spacebars syntax fields from my template or pass my returned event data into my helpers somehow. Everything is published and subscribed properly too.

Problem: I am trying to make it so users can click an "Add" button next to any of the people in a directory list (DirectoryList collection) and have that users information be added to a Contacts List collection. Its simply a messaging app where a person can scroll a directory of everyone and add users to their contacts list. Here are my files:

templates > directoryList.html

```
<template name="directoryList">
    {{> searchDirectory}}
    <ul>
        {{#each directoryList}}
            <li>
                {{firstname}} {{lastname}} &nbsp; <button name="addFriend" id="addFriend">Add</button>
            </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

helpers>directoryList.js

```
Template.directoryList.helpers({

    'directoryList': function(){
        return DirectoryList.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
    }

});
```

events>directoryList.js

```
Template.directoryList.events({

  'click .addFriend': function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
        var currentContact = DirectoryList.findOne(this._id);
        var currentContactFirstname = currentContact.firstname;
        var currentContactLastname = currentContact.lastname;
        var currentContactEmail = currentContact.email;
        console.log("test");

        ContactsList.insert({
            firstname: currentContactFirstname,
            lastname: currentContactLastname,
            email: currentContactEmail,
            createdBy: currentUserId
        });
    }
});
```

its obviously throwing me an error for the {{}} syntax in my event but i dont know what else to do or how to get this to work. Thought it might be able to inherit from the template those fields but i guess not?

Comment: Questions are easier to answer when you point right to the problem. Which line is throwing the error, and what is being printed to the console? Also, is `currentContact` being fetched properly?

Comment: I apologize. It isnt showing any errors in the console or the command prompt, basically just simple a button being clicked that does nothing.

And nothing is being printed to the console. I have the console.log("test") to be printed as a test but its not getting printed.

As far as currentContact I _assumed_ it is. I have a collection called DirectoryList that is published and subscribed to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You event handler is for `addButton` class, where you button doesn't have `addButton` class. You need to change id to class in your template.

```
<template name="directoryList">
    {{> searchDirectory}}
    <ul>
        {{#each directoryList}}
            <li>
                {{firstname}} {{lastname}} &nbsp; <button name="addFriend" class="addFriend">Add</button> <!-- CHANGED ID TO CLASS FOR THIS BUTTON -->
            </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

And you can follow other answer to avoid unnecessary query to improve performance.

Hope it helps.

Comment: YOU ARE THE BEST! such a simple error and it fixed everything. been stuck on this for days. Thank you thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your event handler `this` already contains the current contact, you don't need to look it up again. You can simplify your event handler down to:

```
Template.directoryList.events({

  'click .addFriend': function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this);

        ContactsList.insert({
            firstname: this.firstname,
            lastname: this.lastname,
            email: this.mail,
            createdBy: Meteor.userId()
        });
    }
});
```